# Extracting JSON text from char response buffer

Tags: c, json

I receive a large chunk of text from my Wi-Fi module.

Which is saved in my response buffer.

```
char wifiResponseBuffer[500];
```

The contents can be seen below :

```
AT+CIPSEND=84

> GET http://api.noteu.co.uk/v1/poll/get/?seria
SEND OK

+IPD,308:{"data":[{"line1":"   Facebook Note    ","line2":"Nathan Weighill also","line3":" commented on Harry ","line4":" Bailey's photo.","beep":1,"received_time":1424976639},{"line1":"   Gmail Message    ","line2":"","line3":"Noteu Error","line4":"","beep":1,"received_time":1424976640}],"summary":{"note_count":2}}
OK

OK
Unlink
```

I have a JSON parser library however need to extract the actual JSON text from the response before it can be parsed. This is at the first occurrence of `{` and last occurrence of `}`.
What combination of string functions can I use in C to find the indexes of these characters and then extract the JSON text.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

[`strchr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) is used to find the first occurrence of a character in a string. [`strrchr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr) finds the last.

Here's a brief example of how you might use these:

```
int test(void)
{
    char wifiResponseBuffer[500];
    int wifi_len;

    // get the WiFi data, leaving 1 byte for a NUL terminator
    wifi_len = get_wifi_response(wifiResponseBuffer, sizeof(wifiResponseBuffer)-1);
    if (wifi_len < 0)
        return -1;          // error

    // NUL-terminate to use with strxxx functions
    wifiResponseBuffer[wifi_len] = '\0';  

    // Find start of JSON data
    const char *json_start = strchr(wifiResponseBuffer, '{');
    if (json_start == NULL)
        return -1;
    json_start++;  // advance past {

    // Find end of JSON data
    const char *json_end = strchr(json_start, '}');
    if (json_end == NULL)
        return -1;

    // Pass the JSON data to the library
    size_t json_len = json_end - json_start;

    do_something_with_json_data(json_start, json_len);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, how would you then extract the string using the pointers these functions return?

Comment: What does "extract" mean? strrchr will return a pointer, which you can presumably pass to your JSON api.

Comment: Yes those return a pointer but I'm trying to get the contents of the string inside the {} marks. I'm trying to get the contents of the characters inside the two pointers. Is there a function we can use to do that?

Comment: Adjust the pointers to their proper offsets (increment the result of `strchr` and decrement the result of `strrchr`) to get the first and last character of that string

Comment: See my updated answer. I show finding the start and the end of the JSON data, subtract the two to find the length of the JSON data, and pass a pointer/length to some other function expecting a string of JSON data.